# How to avoid from using the defined mirror with a different profile in Maven?

Tags: maven, maven-2

My project at work is using an Artifactory as mirror of *Maven*. So there is the following setting in `~/.m2/settings.xml`:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                  https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>artifactory</id>
            <username>rx</username>
            <password>67CoHEdAxq6PALFzoB</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>artifactory</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <url>https://dev.mycompany.com/artifactory/maven-all</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
</settings>
```

As a result, all the repositories will download dependencies or plugins from the mirror: `https://dev.mycompany.com/artifactory/maven-all`. However, I need to develop my own projects on the same PC without using the mirror but only the *maven central repository*, https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2. So **I intend to use a `profile`, inside which the repository has a unique id, `private`, then make use of `<mirrorOf>*,!private</mirrorOf>` to be prevented from using the Artifactory mirror**. The changed `settings.xml` looks like this:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                  https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>artifactory</id>
            <username>rx</username>
            <password>67CoHEdAxq6PALFzoB</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>artifactory</id>
            <mirrorOf>*,!private</mirrorOf>
            <url>https://dev.mycompany.com/artifactory/maven-all</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>private</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>private</id>
                    <id>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</id>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</settings>
```

**Problem:** when making use of the profile `private` to generate a project with the following command:

```
mvn -P private archetype:generate -DgroupId=rx.practice.servlet -DartifactId=servlet -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.4 -DinteractiveMode=fa[Clse
```

Maven still tries to download the plugin from the mirror, where does not contain those plugins. Anyone can explain why? and How to fix it?

Comment: Couldn't you just use a second settings.xml?

Comment: Currently I am using another settings.xml, but with the solution mentioned above I got this problem. This means that I still dont have correct understanding on the configuration in settings.xml. So still would like to figure it out